# How can I use source script with variables in CygWin?

Tags: variables, cygwin, ksh

I'm trying to use external script with variables, but in result I get only "no such file or directory".

*1st.ksh*

```
   #!bin/ksh
   PATHNAME = `dirname $0`
   . $PATHNAME/2nd.ksh
   Echo $EXTVAR
```

*2nd.ksh*

```
   #!bin/ksh
   EXTVAR=1
```

I tried to use "Source" instead of "." (`Source $PATHNAME/2nd.ksh`) and I get the same result.
To run script I'm using full path to the script - cygdrive/e/Folder/1st.ksh.
2nd.ksh in this path too (cygdrive/e/Folder/).
All rights was granted for both files (`chmod u=rwx,g=rwx,o=rwx filename`).
If I put files in cygwin home path (/home/username/) I have the same.

Please help to understand what I'm doing wrong.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

- `$()` should be used in ksh instead of ``` `` ``` ([link](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/x7369.html))
- `.` should be user instead of `source` ([link](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/x7369.html))
- "=" must not be surrounded with spaces. You should write: `PATHNAME=$(dirname $0)`
- you should be aware of case-sensitiveness: `echo`, `source`